# If condition in xpquery

Tags: .net, express, frameworks, xaf, xpo

```
var a = (from t in unitOfWork1.Query<LedgerPosting>().Where(t => t.Oid == 1)
         group t by new { t.LedgerId.Oid, t.LedgerId.Name, t.LedgerId.OpeningBalance }
         into grp
            select new
                {
                    grp.Key.Oid,
                    grp.Key.Name,
                    grp.Key.OpeningBalance,
                    Debit = grp.Sum(t => t.Debit),
                    Credit = grp.Sum(t => t.Credit),
                    ClosingStock = (grp.Key.OpeningBalance + grp.Sum(t => t.Debit) - grp.Sum(t => t.Credit))
                }
        ).ToList();
```

In this i want to pass if condition like if closing stock is negative like closing stock is -2850 so value should be display like `2850 Cr`
and closing stock is positive like 2850 so value should be displayed like `2850 Dr`.

How can it Possible.?
Help me Please.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another `.Select()`.

```
a.Select(x => Math.Abs(x.ClosingStock) + (x.ClosingStock < 0 ? " Cr" : " Dr"))
```